# Directions on how to index words and annotate with their type (entity, etc) and then Elasticsearch/w.e. returns these words with the annotations?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, nlp, sphinx

I'm trying to build a very simple NLP chat (I could even say pseudo-NLP?), where I want to identify a fixed subset of intentions (verbs, sentiments) and entities (products, etc)

It's a kind of entity identification or named-entity recognition, but I'm not sure I need a full fledged NER solution for what I want to achieve. **I don't care if the person types cars instead of car. HE HAS to type the EXACT word.** So no need to deal with language stuff here.

**It doesn't need to identity and classify the words, I'm just looking for a way that when I search a phrase, it returns all results that contains each word of if.**

I want to index something like:

```
want [type: intent]
buy [type: intent]
computer [type: entity]
car [type: entity]
```

Then the user will type:

> I want to buy a car.

Then I send this phrase to ElasticSearch/Solr/w.e. and it should return me something like below (it doesn't have to be structured like that, but each word should come with its type):

```
[
    {"word":"want", "type:"intent"},
    {"word":"buy", "type":"intent"},
    {"word":"car","type":"car"}
]
```

---

The approach I came with was Indexing each word as:

```
{
    "word": "car",
    "type": "entity"
}
{
    "word": "buy",
    "type": "intent"
}
```

And then I provide the whole phrase, searching by "word". But I had no success so far, because Elastic Search doesn't return any of the words, even although phrases contains words that are indexed.

**Any insights/ideas/tips to keep this using one of the main search engines?**

**If I do need to use a dedicated NER solution**, what would be the approach to annotate words like this, **without the need to worry about fixing typos, multi-languages, etc?** I want to return results only if the person types the intents and entities exactly as they are, so not an advanced NLP solution.

Curiously I didn't find much about this on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a basic `index` and indexed some documents like this

```
PUT nlpindex/mytype/1
{
    "word": "buy",
    "type": "intent"
}
```

I used [`query string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html?q=query%20st) to search for all the words that appear in a phrase

```
GET nlpindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "I want to buy a car",
      "default_field": "word"
    }
  }
}
```

By default the `operator` is **OR** so it will search for every single word in the phrase in `word` field.

This is the results I  get

```
"hits": [
     {
        "_index": "nlpindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.09427826,
        "_source": {
           "word": "car",
           "type": "entity"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "nlpindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.09427826,
        "_source": {
           "word": "want",
           "type": "intent"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "nlpindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.09427826,
        "_source": {
           "word": "buy",
           "type": "intent"
        }
     }
  ]
```

Does this help?

Comment: I feel embarrassed because you used a basic Elasticsearch indexing and search to accomplish what I was over engineering. I didn't even try the basic concepts, I went straight to researching OpenNLP, UIMA, etc. Should've stayed on the basics. Thank you :)